# Visual Basic Supports

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm making a system using SAPI(Speech Applications Programming Interface) in Visual Basic the question is how Can I Add Male & Female voices to my  Text To Speech Application

Public Class Form1

```
Dim voices As 
Dim sapi As Object = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Male" And ComboBox2.SelectedItem = "100" Then
        sapi.voice = sapi.getvoices.item(8)
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
        sapi.speak(TextBox1.Text)
    End If

End Sub
```

here is my sample code (THERES a LOT OF ERROR IN THERE AND MY SOURCE IS YOUTUBE)

[Here is my sample web app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lV2p.png)

Hoping you can help me with this